# Writing Appointment superclass with 3 subclasses and tester. Everything compiles but no response from program after user input

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass, appointment

Implement a superclass Appointment and subclasses Onetime, Daily, and Monthly. An appointment has a description (for example, “see the dentist”) and occurs on one or more dates. Write a method occursOn(int year, int month, int day) that checks whether the appointment occurs on that date. For example, for a monthly appointment, you must check whether the day of the month matches. Then fill an array of Appointment objects with a mixture of appointments. Have the user enter a date and print out all appointments that occur on that date.

There should be appointments already created and you are simply asking the users for a date to check against them.

A method OccursOn inside each of the sub classes that checks whether the appointment occurs on that date (OneTime), day (Day) or month (Month). Ask the user to enter a date to check. Based on what the user selected, OccursOn inside each of the sub class should run and display any matching appointment and associated descriptions. For OneTime subclass, OccursOn need three inputs (Year, Month and Day) to validate, for Day subclass, OccursOn needs one input (Day) to validate, and for Month subclass, OccursOn need one input (Month) to validate. OccursOn is different for different subclasses.

The tester should be fine. I need superclass and subclasses to match the tester class. I'm not sure what part of my code doesn't match up.

There may be some code in there not involved directly with the current program as I have been trying different things to fix the problem with no solution.

```
public class Appointment{



    private int day;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private String description;

    public int getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }

    /**
     * @param patientName sets patient name
     */
    public void setDay(int day)
    {
        this.day = day;
    }

     /**
     * 
     */
    public int getMonth()
    {
        return month;
    }

    /**
     * @param patientName sets patient name
     */
    public void setMonth(int month)
    {
        this.month = month;
    }

     /**
     * 
     */
    public int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }

    /**
     * @param patientName sets patient name
     */
    public void setYear(int year)
    {
        this.year = year;
    }

    /**
     * 
    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
    */

    /**
     * @param patientName sets patient name

    public void setDescription(String description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }
    */

    boolean occursOn (int day, int month, int year)
    {
        if( (this.day == day) || (this.month == month) || (this.year == year))
            {
                return true;
            }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     Converts appointment to string description
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        return description;
    }
}




import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Daily extends Appointment{



    private ArrayList<Integer>daily;

    public Daily(int day, int month, int year, String description)
    {
        daily = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public boolean occursOn (int day)
    {
        daily.add(day);
        {
             String whatDay = "" + daily.size();
        }

        return true;
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Monthly extends Appointment{



    private ArrayList<Integer>monthly;

    public Monthly(int day, int month, int year, String description)
    {
        monthly = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public boolean occursOn (int month)
    {
        monthly.add(month);
        {
             String whatMonth = "" + monthly.size();
        }

        return true;
    }


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OneTime extends Appointment{



    private ArrayList<Integer>oneTime;
    int oneAppointment;

    public OneTime(int day, int month, int year, String description)
    {
        oneTime = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public boolean occursOn (int day, int month, int year)
    {
        oneTime.add(oneAppointment);
        {
             String whatMonthDayYear = "" + oneTime.size();
        }

        return true;
    }


import java.util.Scanner;

public class AppointmentDemo{



    public static void main(String[] args){
        Appointment[] appointments = new Appointment [4];
        appointments[0] = new Daily (2, 10, 2018, "Brush your teeth.");
        appointments[1] = new Monthly (2, 10, 2018, "Brush your teeth.");
        appointments[2] = new OneTime (2, 10, 2018, "Brush your teeth.");

        System.out.println("Enter a date (month, day, year) to list" + "appointments: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int month = in.nextInt();
        int day = in.nextInt();
        int year = in.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++){
            if (appointments[i].occursOn(month, day, year)){
                System.out.println(appointments[i]);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

There are no current error messages. The program just does not respond after input from the user. Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Appointment[] appointments = new Appointment [4];` in the last block of code: Why do you have a unused index?

Comment: Did you enter 3 numbers?

Comment: Next time, please attempt to debug your program using System.out.print() statements to find variable values throughout your program.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Scanner` is still waiting for full input, so nothing happens. (Thanks to @csabinho)

Okay, let's say you entered any three numbers. You would get a NullPointerException, because each `Appointment` object in your `appointments[]` array has a `null` `day`, `month`, and `year.` None of your constructors actually define your variables.